# Как отлаживать C++ код andoid webview shell из chromium?

Tags: android, webview, android-ndk, android-webview, chromium

У меня стоит задача сделать кастомный android webview на основе его исходников из проекта chromium.
Я могу его сбилдить и установить на девайс, но есть проблема с отладкой. Исходники содержат, например, файл chromium/src/build/android/adb_gdb_android_webview_shell с помощью которого gdb вроде подключается к запущенному тестовому шеллу. Но отладка из терминала с текстовой расстановкой брейков не удобна.

Есть ли какой-то более удобный отладчик с графическим интерфесом и как с помощью него отлаживать web view shell? Или какие-то советы по оптимизации работы с gdb?
Что вы используете?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то это задачу решает обычная IDE, например в Android Studio для нативного кода применен отладчик LLDB.
Еще есть IDA Pro, но она предназначена для реверс-инжиниринга, а главное, в некоторых местах она крайне медленно работает, нет поддержки многопоточности и т.п., я так и не дождался подключения к ее отладчику для Android при достаточно большом приложении.

Comment: У chromium их билд-тулза делает скрипты gradle только для пары тестовых java приложений, С++ код туда не включается.  Можно ли подцепить С++ код в Android Studio в таком случае и как?

Comment: @aabramovsky Можно в любом случае, а как - вопрос слишком узкий, чтобы вам бесплатно на него ответили.